# Different View depending on OS

Tags: c#, wpf, view, app.xaml

I have an application were in the App.xaml file are elements that are avaible only on windows 8 +, so on windows 7 its crashing. Is there any good solution were I can provide different App.xaml (views) depending on the OS?

Comment: Better have different projects to create different builds for each OS

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger on the [`Environment.OSVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx). This would allow you to know the OS Version that your app is running on and then, I would suggest the pattern detailed [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/).

Comment: In general, the condition of distinguishing the OS version ia a minor problem. The main problem is changing a view depending on some conditions. I'm wondering how this is handled by software companies and what is the best choice. Is there any simple way having a few .xaml files and maneuvering between them.